# sql script to create generate consecutive numbers depending on a column and again start with 1

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, oracle11g

I have a table with 3 columns in which one is empty.

its like this,

```
c1    c2    c3
1    1000  
1    1001
1    1004
2    1005
2    1007
3    1009
```

I want to insert values to c3 like

```
c1    c2    c3
1    1000    1 
1    1001    2
1    1004    3
2    1005    1
2    1007    2
3    1009    1
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: The desired value for some row's `c3` is the count of all rows with the same `c1` which have a `c2` greater than or equal to that of the row in question.  Tell us the RDBMs and someone can give you the correct UPDATE syntax.

Comment: @user1253754 : Is c2 unique for each c1?

Comment: DB is Oracle XE 11g. I have a huge set of records to migrate and then need to add this column. And c3 is dependent on c1

Comment: c2 is unique for each c1

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is the one that pilcrow describes above: for each record R, `c3` is equal to the number of records that have the same `c1` as R, and a `c2` that is less than or equal to that of R. As a SQL statement:

```
UPDATE table_name t
   SET c3 =
        ( SELECT COUNT(1)
            FROM table_name
           WHERE c1 = t.c1
             AND c2 <= t.c2
        )
;
```

(Replace `table_name` with your table-name, of course.)

Comment: very good logic .. 

but you are skipping one condition -- when c2 has duplicate value for a single value in c1...

this condition is not in this example so hoping that c2 will be unique in case of every value in c1 column

Comment: @pratikgarg: The OP explicitly said that "c2 is unique for each c1".

Comment: I am sorry about OP.. are you telling about OutPut here... ??
well in my previous comment I told **in this situation** it will update with wrong values.. 

if this is not a case ... means if c2 is unique then this query is perfect. as I told I just like this approach.. 
but please forgive me .. still I have not seen this condition specifically defined that c2 will be unique for column name c1...

Comment: @pratikgarg: "OP" means "original poster". The original poster explicitly wrote, in a comment above: "c2 is unique for each c1".

Answer (score 2):

This might be faster than the nested sub-select (but you will need to test it)

```
merge into your_table u
using
(
    select c1,
           c2,
           row_number() over (partition by c1 order by c2) as rn
    from your_table
) t on (t.c1 = u.c1 and t.c2 = u.c2)
when matched then
update
    set u.c3 = rn;
```